# Text area not being rendered

Tags: javascript, html

I made a website that takes what you put into the text area and displays it to another text area below.

So what you do is once you go to the site you type in the text area. Once you are satisfied you need to tab out of the text box. Once you are tabbed out you should see the text you entered at the bottom of the site. Once it is in the rendered section you should be able to modify it by using javscript. You can change the color, font size etc with sliders. The site looks correct and seems to be fine but my text wont render. I think I am missing something in my html because I know the java-script is all correct. I think I may have a spelling error or something I am not catching. The html needs to match the javascript and I am too close to this see an error. All help is welcome, thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--
  New Perspectives on HTML and CSS
  Tutorial 6
  Case Problem 3
  WidgetMage
  Author: James DuBois
  Date:   4/14/2015
  Filename:         cssDemo.htm
  Supporting files: back.png, cssForms.css, modernizr-1.5.js,
                    rundemo.js, wm.css, wmlogo.png
-->

<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>CSS Styles Demo</title>
<script src="modernizr-1.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="rundemo.js"></script>

<link href="wm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="cssforms.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

  <header>
     <img src="wmlogo.png" alt="WidgetMage" />
     <nav class="horizontal">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Widgets</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Demos</a></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>
  </header>

  <nav class="vertical">
     <ul>
        <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Animations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Calendars</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cookies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drag &amp; Drop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Image Tools</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Icons</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Layout Tools</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List Boxes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menus</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Popups</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ribbons</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sliders</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Spinners</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Toolbars</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tooltips</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tree Views</a></li>
        <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tips &amp; Tricks</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">White Papers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">User Forums</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">External Links</a></li>
        <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Demonstrations</a></li>
        <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>

  <section>
     <h1>CSS Demo</h1>
     <p>Select the CSS style values from the form below and preview the
        effect on the sample text in the preview box.
     </p>

        <form>
           <fieldset id="textstring">
              <label>Enter your sample text below</label>
                 <textarea autofocus  tabindex="1" wrap="hard" name="sampletext" id="sampletext">
                     
                 </textarea>
           </fieldset>

           <fieldset id="fonts">

              <legend>
                 Fonts
              </legend>

              <label for="fontfamily">Font Family</label>
              <select id="fontfamily" name="fontfamily">
                 <optgroup label="generic">
                 <option value="default">default</option>
                 <option value="serif">serif</option>
                 <option value="sans-serif">sans-serif</option>
                 <option value="monospace">monospace</option>
                 <option value="cursive">cursive</option>
                 <option value="fantasy">fantasy</option>
                 </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="specific">
                 <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
                 <option value="'Book Antiqua'">'Book Antiqua'</option>
                 <option value="'Courier New'">'Courier New'</option>
                 <option value="Geneva">Geneva</option>
                 <option value="Helvetica">Helvetica</option>
                 <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
                 <option value="Palatino">Palatino</option>
                 <option value="'Times New Roman'">'Times New Roman'</option>
                    </optgroup>
              </select>

              <label for="fontstyle">Font Style</label>
                 <select id="fontstyle" name="fontstyle">
                    <option value="normal">normal</option>
                    <option value="italic">italic</option>
                    <option value="oblique">oblique</option>
                 </select>

                 <label for="fontweight">Font Weight</label>
                    <select id="fontweight" name="fontweight">
                       <option value="normal">normal</option>
                       <option value="bold">bold</option>
                    </select>

                 <label for="textdecoration">Text Decoration</label>
                    <select id="textdecoration" name="textdecoration">
                       <option value="none">none</option>
                       <option value="line-through">line-through</option>
                       <option value="overline">overline</option>
                       <option value="underline">underline</option>
                    </select>

                 <label for="texttransform">Text Transform</label>
                    <select id="texttransform" name="texttransform">
                       <option value="none">none</option>
                       <option value="capitalize">capitalize</option>
                       <option value="lowercase">lowercase</option>
                       <option value="uppercase">uppercase</option>
                    </select>

                 <label for="fontvariant">Font Variant</label>
                    <select id="fontvariant" name="fontvariant">
                       <option value="normal">normal</option>
                       <option value="small-caps">small-caps</option>
                    </select>
           </fieldset>

           <fieldset id="colors">
                
                <legend>
                 Colors
              </legend>

                 <label for="color">Font Color (hexadecimal)</label>
                 <input type="color" value="#000000" placeholder="#rrggbb" name="fontcolor" id="fontcolor">

                 <label for="color">Background Color (hexadecimal)</label>
                 <input type="color" value="#FFFFF" placeholder="#rrggbb" name="backgroundcolor" id="backgroundcolor">



           </fieldset>

           <fieldset id="sizes">
                

                <legend>
                 Sizes
              </legend>

              <label>Font Size (px)</label>
                 <input type="range" value="14" min="8" max="40" step="1" name="fontsize" id="fontsize">

              <label>Letter Spacing (px)</label>
                 <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="10" step="1" name="letterspacing" id="letterspacing">

              <label>Word Spacing (px)</label>
                 <input type="range" value="14" min="8" max="40" step="1" name="wordspacing" id="wordspacing">

              <label>Line Height (em)</label>
                 <input type="range" value="1" min="0" max="4" step="0.2" name="lineheight" id="lineheight">

              <label>Text Indent (px)</label>
                 <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="10" step="1" name="textindent" id="textindent">



           </fieldset>

           <button type="button" id="removestyles">Remove Styles</button>

        </form>


     <h2>Rendered Text</h2>
     <div id="output"></div>
  </section>

   
</body>

</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
/*
   New Perspectives on HTML and CSS
   Tutorial 6
   Case Problem 3

   Author:   Anna Lopez  
   Date:     3/1/2014

   Filename: rundemo.js

   Purpose: The purpose of this program is to update the
            appearance of the rendered text based on the styles
            selected by the user from the form.


*/

function updatePreview() {
   formStyles=document.forms[0];
   inputtext=formStyles.sampletext.value;

   previewobject=document.getElementById("output");
   previewobject.innerHTML=inputtext.replace(/\n/g,"<br />");
   

   ffi=formStyles.fontfamily.selectedIndex;
   previewobject.style.fontFamily=formStyles.fontfamily.options[ffi].text;

   fsi=formStyles.fontstyle.selectedIndex;
   previewobject.style.fontStyle=formStyles.fontstyle.options[fsi].text;

   fwi=formStyles.fontweight.selectedIndex;
   previewobject.style.fontWeight=formStyles.fontweight.options[fwi].text;

   tdi=formStyles.textdecoration.selectedIndex;
   previewobject.style.textDecoration=formStyles.textdecoration.options[tdi].text;

   tti=formStyles.texttransform.selectedIndex;
   previewobject.style.textTransform=formStyles.texttransform.options[tti].text;
 
   fvi=formStyles.fontvariant.selectedIndex;
   previewobject.style.fontVariant=formStyles.fontvariant.options[fvi].text;  

   previewobject.style.color=formStyles.color.value;
   previewobject.style.backgroundColor=formStyles.backgroundcolor.value;

   previewobject.style.fontSize=formStyles.fontsize.value + "px";
   previewobject.style.letterSpacing=formStyles.letterspacing.value+"px";
   previewobject.style.wordSpacing=formStyles.wordspacing.value+"px";
   previewobject.style.lineHeight=formStyles.lineheight.value+"em";
   previewobject.style.textIndent=formStyles.textindent.value+"px"; 
}

window.onload=function() {
   formStyles=document.forms[0];

   formStyles.fontfamily.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.fontstyle.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.fontweight.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.textdecoration.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.texttransform.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.fontvariant.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.color.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.backgroundcolor.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.fontsize.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.letterspacing.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.wordspacing.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.lineheight.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.textindent.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.textstring.onchange=updatePreview;

   document.getElementById("removestyles").onclick = redo;
}

function redo() {
   window.location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console tells you where your problem is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of undefined

**on line:**

```
formStyles.color.onchange=updatePreview;
```

**change to:**

```
formStyles.fontcolor.onchange=updatePreview;
```

*then  we get:*

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

**on line:**

```
previewobject.style.color=formStyles.color.value;
```

**change to:**

```
previewobject.style.color=formStyles.fontcolor.value;
```

---

```js
function updatePreview() {
   formStyles=document.forms[0];
   inputtext=formStyles.sampletext.value;

   previewobject=document.getElementById("output");
   previewobject.innerHTML=inputtext.replace(/\n/g,"<br />");


   ffi=formStyles.fontfamily.selectedIndex;
   previewobject.style.fontFamily=formStyles.fontfamily.options[ffi].text;

   fsi=formStyles.fontstyle.selectedIndex;
   previewobject.style.fontStyle=formStyles.fontstyle.options[fsi].text;

   fwi=formStyles.fontweight.selectedIndex;
   previewobject.style.fontWeight=formStyles.fontweight.options[fwi].text;

   tdi=formStyles.textdecoration.selectedIndex;
   previewobject.style.textDecoration=formStyles.textdecoration.options[tdi].text;

   tti=formStyles.texttransform.selectedIndex;
   previewobject.style.textTransform=formStyles.texttransform.options[tti].text;

   fvi=formStyles.fontvariant.selectedIndex;
   previewobject.style.fontVariant=formStyles.fontvariant.options[fvi].text;  

   previewobject.style.color=formStyles.fontcolor.value;
   previewobject.style.backgroundColor=formStyles.backgroundcolor.value;

   previewobject.style.fontSize=formStyles.fontsize.value + "px";
   previewobject.style.letterSpacing=formStyles.letterspacing.value+"px";
   previewobject.style.wordSpacing=formStyles.wordspacing.value+"px";
   previewobject.style.lineHeight=formStyles.lineheight.value+"em";
   previewobject.style.textIndent=formStyles.textindent.value+"px"; 
}

window.onload=function() {
   formStyles=document.forms[0];

   formStyles.fontfamily.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.fontstyle.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.fontweight.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.textdecoration.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.texttransform.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.fontvariant.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.fontcolor.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.backgroundcolor.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.fontsize.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.letterspacing.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.wordspacing.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.lineheight.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.textindent.onchange=updatePreview;
   formStyles.textstring.onchange=updatePreview;

   document.getElementById("removestyles").onclick = redo;
}

function redo() {
   window.location.reload();
}
```

```html
<body>

  <section>
     <h1>CSS Demo</h1>
     <p>Select the CSS style values from the form below and preview the
        effect on the sample text in the preview box.
     </p>

        <form>
           <fieldset id="textstring">
              <label>Enter your sample text below</label>
                 <textarea autofocus  tabindex="1" wrap="hard" name="sampletext" id="sampletext">

                 </textarea>
           </fieldset>

           <fieldset id="fonts">

              <legend>
                 Fonts
              </legend>

              <label for="fontfamily">Font Family</label>
              <select id="fontfamily" name="fontfamily">
                 <optgroup label="generic">
                 <option value="default">default</option>
                 <option value="serif">serif</option>
                 <option value="sans-serif">sans-serif</option>
                 <option value="monospace">monospace</option>
                 <option value="cursive">cursive</option>
                 <option value="fantasy">fantasy</option>
                 </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="specific">
                 <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
                 <option value="'Book Antiqua'">'Book Antiqua'</option>
                 <option value="'Courier New'">'Courier New'</option>
                 <option value="Geneva">Geneva</option>
                 <option value="Helvetica">Helvetica</option>
                 <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
                 <option value="Palatino">Palatino</option>
                 <option value="'Times New Roman'">'Times New Roman'</option>
                    </optgroup>
              </select>

              <label for="fontstyle">Font Style</label>
                 <select id="fontstyle" name="fontstyle">
                    <option value="normal">normal</option>
                    <option value="italic">italic</option>
                    <option value="oblique">oblique</option>
                 </select>

                 <label for="fontweight">Font Weight</label>
                    <select id="fontweight" name="fontweight">
                       <option value="normal">normal</option>
                       <option value="bold">bold</option>
                    </select>

                 <label for="textdecoration">Text Decoration</label>
                    <select id="textdecoration" name="textdecoration">
                       <option value="none">none</option>
                       <option value="line-through">line-through</option>
                       <option value="overline">overline</option>
                       <option value="underline">underline</option>
                    </select>

                 <label for="texttransform">Text Transform</label>
                    <select id="texttransform" name="texttransform">
                       <option value="none">none</option>
                       <option value="capitalize">capitalize</option>
                       <option value="lowercase">lowercase</option>
                       <option value="uppercase">uppercase</option>
                    </select>

                 <label for="fontvariant">Font Variant</label>
                    <select id="fontvariant" name="fontvariant">
                       <option value="normal">normal</option>
                       <option value="small-caps">small-caps</option>
                    </select>
           </fieldset>

           <fieldset id="colors">

                <legend>
                 Colors
              </legend>

                 <label for="color">Font Color (hexadecimal)</label>
                 <input type="color" value="#000000" placeholder="#rrggbb" name="fontcolor" id="fontcolor">

                 <label for="color">Background Color (hexadecimal)</label>
                 <input type="color" value="#FFFFF" placeholder="#rrggbb" name="backgroundcolor" id="backgroundcolor">



           </fieldset>

           <fieldset id="sizes">


                <legend>
                 Sizes
              </legend>

              <label>Font Size (px)</label>
                 <input type="range" value="14" min="8" max="40" step="1" name="fontsize" id="fontsize">

              <label>Letter Spacing (px)</label>
                 <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="10" step="1" name="letterspacing" id="letterspacing">

              <label>Word Spacing (px)</label>
                 <input type="range" value="14" min="8" max="40" step="1" name="wordspacing" id="wordspacing">

              <label>Line Height (em)</label>
                 <input type="range" value="1" min="0" max="4" step="0.2" name="lineheight" id="lineheight">

              <label>Text Indent (px)</label>
                 <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="10" step="1" name="textindent" id="textindent">



           </fieldset>

           <button type="button" id="removestyles">Remove Styles</button>

        </form>


     <h2>Rendered Text</h2>
     <div id="output"></div>
  </section>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to DTing's answer, to help you check bugs like these, you could hit <kbd>F12</kbd> and reload your page. Check for errors in the Console tab, in this case:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of undefined

You could also check the Source tab, that would give you a hint on where the error is.

*No rep to comment